# What happens if not copy every jar. file into eclipse to use Selenium?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jar

I am setting up Selenium right now and i have to copy the Selenium files into my eclipse project. Unfortunately, every tutorial has different files which they are adding to the Eclipse project, mostly because they are using older Selenium versions. 
Currently, i just added all jar. files from the "libs" folder and also the jar file called "client-combined-3.5.3-nodeps". So i hope these are all files i need.
My question is, what happens if some files are missing? Is Selenium then not usable correctly?

Comment: Yes it's can interrupt your test case..Use Maven project its good for manage library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium Java client provides us the APIs through different packages. So when we need to use the APIs we have to make the necessary imports as well.

Now, if you miss out to add certain Selenium related jars in your Project, some methods from your `main()` or `@test` Class may not get resolved due to absence of the imports. Hence your program/script will show you errors as unresolved methods and will the program will not get compiled/executed.

Hence, it's always a good idea to add all the jars in your project from the released `Selenium Client SDK`.

At times, there may exist certain methods which are defined in multiple packages. For example method `abc()` may be defined in `java.util.pqr;` as well as in `org.openqa.selenium.xyz;`. In those cases we have to make our imports wisely as per our requirement.